# PHP code gets printed on the loaded page

Tags: php

Hi I recently reinstalled my windows and downloaded and installed xampp but for some reason when I try to load any typ of php code the page does not get loaded on the server but is printed on the HTML page.Here is what I mean:

[image]

This image is from the source code of the loaded page.This is the code I am using:

```
   <?php
        $a = "Maria";

        echo "We're going to Paris with $a";
        echo 'We\'re going to Paris with $a';      
    ?>
```

I have restarted xampp 3 times it shows apache and mysql is running.Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Does the name of your file end in `.php`?

Comment: Did you save it has `.html` or `.php` .. are you also sure you have PHP installed on your server ??

Comment: Check ur http.conf file. Its an apache config file. It sgould have handler for php type requests.

Comment: the extension was the problem I did not realize I changed the extension by mistake saved it like this a.indez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have the right file extension
2. Configure the web server to recognize php.